# How to edit custom node socket noddle style as dotted line?

Tags: node-editor

I am looking for a solution to customize a node link type, inside a custom nodetree.
In standard nodes, there are some data sockets that do link with a dotted line noddle, how to reproduce this with custom node? i can´t find it in the api...

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: I don't think it's available to the API

Comment: ok, i saw some dev.talk regarding this topic, seems that the style will not be exposed.